# How to get Session Id / Session Key from of current session in python requests library

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, session, python-requests, logout

I have succeed in login to a site using login data and post method of session object which is created by `session = requests.session()` using requests library of python3. Now I want to log out that site. When I check the link in logout button in actual site it's like this

> https://mysite.domain/login/logout.php?sesskey=xxxxxxx

Now I want to find the value of the sesskey. How to get the value of the current session. Or are theri any alternative method to sign out ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use urlparse for this.

```
import urlparse
url = "https://mysite.domain/login/logout.php?sesskey=xxxxxxx"
sess = urlparse.urlparse(url)[4]
print(sess.split('=')[1])
```

`xxxxxxx`